# PHP pdo_sqlsrv: insert unicode strings by default on MS SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, unicode, utf-8

I have a database PHP application that can work with MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite. The application uses PDO and assumes the database content is Unicode.

I am adding the support for MS SQL SERVER using the pdo_sqlsrv driver and the only solution I have found is to modify all the queries (it's really a lot of work) adding the N prefix in front of the strings for the INSERT and UPDATE queries.

Is there any smarter solution to insert unicode by default? Like a PDO or SQL SERVER setting?

Since all the queries are executed by a function (it's my own layer over PDO), I have also thought about adding a regular expression that modifies the queries before the execution but I think it's quite tricky.

Thanks.

Comment: "Unicode" is a wide area. Do you refer to hard-coded string literals (`N'Foo'`) and only that? Is everything else (`PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING => PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8` flag, `NVARCHAR` columns...) already handled?

Comment: SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8 and NVARCHAR are handled (actually SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8 is the default, so you don't need it but I tried anyway), but it's not enough, without the N prefix I haven't found any way to properly store unicode content in a nvarchar field.

Comment: About the first part of your comment: we can also focus on a smallest problem, let's say there is a web page having utf8 charset and a form we use to insert data into da mssql DB; let's say a user types this string in the form: 大人, can I store it in a nvarchar field without using the N prefix?

Comment: The problem is that SQL Server interprets the bytes in strings as different encodings (`''` as ANSI, `N''` as Unicode) in at least some circumstances. I don't know if it's mandatory or can be configured in some way. About `大人`, the `N` prefix only makes sense in strings literals; bound parameters should be totally unaffected. If you generate string literals from `$_POST` data then you have a different problem :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment; yes, I know the problem and the fact that is limited to string literals but is there a solution? You said "at least some circumstances", are there cases when this doesn't happen?

Comment: E.g. running queries from SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Ok, so not with PHP and apparently there isn't any solution.

Answer (score 0):

After you set up your connection to the DB you need to add the PDO Attributes:

```
$mssql_connection->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8);
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/pdostatement-setattribute?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: That's not enough, without the N prefix in front of the strings I haven't found any way to properly store unicode content in a nvarchar/ntext field. Furthermore SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8 is the default setting so you actually don't need it, but I tried to use it anyway.